# jspdf is not making pdf of right size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jspdf

I am making a resume builder app in `react-js`. I am at the stage where when users clicks on download button the resume should be downloaded as pdf. For this purpose i am using `js-pdf`, but the problem is that when i click on download button the pdf generated by `js-pdf` is not right. Its like zoomed or the font size is too big i don't know what is the problem.

I have given the width 210mm and height 297mm to the html element who need to be converted into pdf. And below is my code to generate and download pdf

```
function handleDownload() {
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]);
    const content = pdfRef.current
    doc.html(content, {
      callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save('newFile');
      }
    });
  }
```

and this is my jsx element which i want to be downloaded as pdf

```
<main id="classic" ref={pdfRef} className='mx-auto bg-white shadow w-[210mm] h-[297mm]'>
  <button onClick={handleDownload} className="bg-mainBlack text-white px-4 py-2 text-xs">download</button>
  {/* Rest inner elements */}
</main>
```

tihs is how the resume looks like in browser (please ignore the styling i have'nt styled it yet)

[image: snapshot of browser render]

this is the picture of how `js-pdf` make its pdf

[image: preview of pdf]

I want the pdf to be the correct size

Comment: The default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units. This should suffice const doc = new jsPDF(). since 210x297 is a4.

Comment: yeah i know i hard coded it myself to see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Oh okay, Is the html styling done with tailwind?

Comment: yes, i am using tailwind css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented using htmltocanvas library.

```
async function handleDownload() {
    const contentCanvas = await html2canvas(document.getElementById("content"));
    const image = contentCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(image, "png", 0, 0);
    doc.save("resumse.pdf");
  }
```

Code Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-joana-veix3x?file=/src/App.js:184-452

Comment: thank you for your time to look into this but i have found the solution. Again thank you for your time. <3

Comment: Awesome, Please post your solution, if possible, thank you :)

Comment: Yeah i have kinda got it but still having some problems 
I have changed the format of the pdf

`const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [1000, 700])`

and also the width and height of the html element but will it make a problem while printing? plus this is not correct a4 size so will it make a problem?

Comment: so i used your solution and it worked perfectly but now there is some color issue the generated pdf have darker shades on right and bottom areas. maybe it's because of html2canvas can you help me get the right colors?

Comment: Update! The issue of darker areas on the border is because of box-shadow. An issue is already opened on html2canvas github but still they have'nt fixed it.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks for the update. You can try the react-pdf library and check if that will solve the color issues. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf